# i18next using Backbone and requireJs not work

Tags: backbone.js, internationalization, requirejs, i18next

im having troubles using i18next with requireJs and Backbone. I have a folder named 'i18n' where all my resources are listed.

content of i18 folder:
    resources-locale_en.js
    resources-locale_es.js
    resources-locale_fr.js
    resources-locale_it.js

content of resources-locale_es.js

```
{
"john doe": "John Doe",
"my profile": "mi perfil",
"settings": "Ajustes",
"my tasks": "mis tareas",
"red": "rojo",
"orange": "orange"
}
```

On my require config.js:

```
.
.
.
 //shim
    i18n: {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }

.
.
.

var i18n = require('i18n');
i18n.init({
    getAsync: false,
    lang: 'en',
    debug: true,
    fallbackLng: false,
    load:'unspecific',
    resGetPath: "__ns_____lng__.js",
    ns: {
        namespaces: ['i18n/resources-locale'],
        defaultNs: 'i18n/resources-locale'
    }
}).done(function() {
    new AppRouter({});
    Backbone.history.start({
        pushState: true
    });
})
```

When DOM is loaded i run:

```
$("[data-i18n]").i18n();
```

but just list elements that content data-i18n, not transform anything

```
[ <span data-i18n=​"My Profile">​</span>​
, <span data-i18n=​"My Tasks">​</span>​
, <span data-i18n=​"Lock">​</span>​
, <span data-i18n=​"Log Out">​</span>​
, <span data-i18n=​"User Profile">​</span>​
, <span data-i18n=​"Dashboard">​</span
]
```

What im doing wrong?